# Detecting when there is a response on an iframe?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have created an AJAX style file download (using an iframe) and all works well... however, I need to detect when the iframe has received a response... see below:

Javascript:

```
function download() {
  var ifrm = $('#iframedownload')[0];
  ifrm.src = '/downloadfile.aspx?fileid=whatever';
  ifrm.onreadystatechange = function () { // Checking
    if (this.readyState == 'complete')
      alert("I would really like this piece to work!");
  };
}
```

C# for downloadfile.aspx:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFileName + "\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", respBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(respBytes); 
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Handle the `<iframe>`'s `onload` and `readystatechanged` events](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2009/06/18/events-to-expect-when-dynamically-loading-iframes-in-javascript.aspx).

Comment: ifrm.contentDocument.onreadystatechange works for IE but not FireFox... only works when the container page first renders...

Comment: Read this page: http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2009/06/18/events-to-expect-when-dynamically-loading-iframes-in-javascript.aspx